# Problema para importar un archivo JS

Tags: javascript, php, html

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto personal en el cual tengo varias paginas que son practicamente iguales. Por esta razon decidi trabajar con template y me cree una cabecera y un footer(De la mitad del cuerpo de la pagina para abajo) que serán reutilizados por todas mis paginas. Así optimizo y cualquier cambio que desee hacer solo lo tendré que hacer en un solo lugar.

Mi problema es el siguiente: Hasta este momento las funcionalidades que necesitaba estaban todos en un archivo js, el cual yo lo importo en mi plantilla footer ya que es el archivo js que utilizan todas mis pagina pero ahora mismo una de esas paginas necesita una funcionalidad adicional que no tienen las otras y necesito hacerlo en un nuevo archivo js. El problema es que no sé donde importar a dicho archivo.

Recuerden que esta pagina solo es un pedazo de codigo que no tiene ni cabecera ni de la mitad del cuerpo para abajo. Espero me hayan entendido. Así se ve la pagina a la cual necesito ponerle mi funcionalidad:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
        header("location:index.php");
    }
    include 'Templates/cabecera.php';
    ?>


<li class="nav-item dropstart">

<a class="nav-link" href="#" id="dropdowOpciones" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
    <?php echo "Hi, ".$_SESSION["first_name"]  ?>
</a>

<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark" aria-labelledby="dropdowOpciones">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
    <ion-icon name="cart" class="iconos_navBar"></ion-icon>
        Carrito
    </a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
    <ion-icon name="create" class="iconos_navBar"></ion-icon>
        Cambiar contraseña
    </a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" id="enlace_salir" href="#">
    <ion-icon name="log-out" class="iconos_navBar"></ion-icon>
        Salir
    </a></li>
  </ul>

</li>


<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">
    <ion-icon name="log-out" class="iconos_navBar"></ion-icon>Salir
</a>
</li>

</ul>

</div>
</div>
</nav>


    <?php
    include 'Templates/cuerpo.php';
    include 'Templates/pie.php';

 ?>
```

Comment: Imaginen que necesito utilizar un nuevo archivo de jquery para esta pagina, en que parte del codigo lo importo? Segun los tutoriales que he visto siempre se hace antes que cierre el body pero si se fijan aqui el body esta en un template, creo que alla no deberia ponerlo puesto que lo que voy a hacer solo le incumbe a esta pagina. Por favor ayudenme, soy nuevo y todavia hay conceptos que no domino.

Comment: Edita la pregunta para agregar el código de `pie.php` y poder sugerirte una solución.

Comment: Gracias hermano , pero ya encontre la solucion. Entre el template cuerpo y el template pie agregue nuevamente mi jquery y mi nuevo archivo js y listo. Funciona a la perfeccion.